# Webpack 4 can't load relative path font

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader

I'm moving from webpack-encore to WebPack and I'm facing to a relative path resolution issue.

I followed the [official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-fonts) and tried this configuration:

```
const
  MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin'),
  path = require('path');

// eslint-disable-next-line one-var
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './assets/js/app.js',
    front: './assets/js/front.js',
    login: './assets/js/login.js',
    // admin: './assets/js/admin.js',
    common: './assets/js/common.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/build/'),
    publicPath: '/build',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  devtool: devMode ? 'inline-source-map' : false,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        // exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        loader: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          // 'resolve-url-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),
  ],
};
```

As you can see, some loader are commented. It's some tests I did after looking for solution on the WWW.

Here is my test css file:

```
@import "~font-icons-nexylan/css/font-icons-nexylan";
```

Simply imported from `app.js`:

```
require('../css/test.scss');
```

Here is the complete errors:

```
ERROR in ./assets/css/test.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./assets/css/test.scss)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/font-icons-nexylan.svg' in '/code/assets/css'
 @ ./assets/css/test.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./assets/css/test.scss) 7:356-398

ERROR in ./assets/css/test.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./assets/css/test.scss)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/font-icons-nexylan.ttf' in '/code/assets/css'
 @ ./assets/css/test.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./assets/css/test.scss) 7:270-312

ERROR in ./assets/css/test.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./assets/css/test.scss)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/font-icons-nexylan.woff' in '/code/assets/css'
 @ ./assets/css/test.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./assets/css/test.scss) 7:187-230

ERROR in ./assets/css/test.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./assets/css/test.scss)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/font-icons-nexylan.woff2' in '/code/assets/css'
 @ ./assets/css/test.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./assets/css/test.scss) 7:102-146
```

I did try with a private library, but I have exactly the same with something like FontAwesome v4.

I'm sure it's quick to solve, but I didn't find anything to help me on StackOverflow yet.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: If I try to import a font library directly from the js file:

```
import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
```

It works and copied the font files.

But it does not if the import is from a SCSS file:

```
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

Comment: one thing to tweak, you must not apply sass-loader to css too. Split that rule into two. `test: /\.(sa|sc)ss$/,` only, do not add css there too

Comment: Interessting. Why? I say other configuration like mine without any issue. I'll try it, but on my case I use only test.scss, so I don't think it will resolve the issue. ;-)